# About Set() and for..in... in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function menuSet(menuArray) {
  let flatmenus = menuArray.flat();//Method gom cac Array con va Array cha thanh 1 Array duy nhat
  let combinedMenu = new Set();//Tao Object trong do Loai bo cac phan tu con trung nhau
  flatmenus.forEach(dish => { //Dua cac phan tu trong Flatmenus vao Object Set() moi duoc tao
    combinedMenu.add(dish)
  });
  const menuCombined = document.querySelector('#combined-menu')
  for (let dish of combinedMenu) {
    let foodNode = document.createElement('li')
    foodNode.innerText = dish;
    menuCombined.appendChild(foodNode);
  }
}
menuSet([["Tacos", "Burgers"], ["Pizza"], ["Burgers", "Fries"]])
```

Why for..in loop can not deal with the object but it comes Ok with Set()?
Doesn't Set() return an Object?

Comment: Sets are iterable as they implement the [iterable protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#the_iterable_protocol), you can see the iterator using `combinedMenu[Symbol.iterator]()`, so they can be used with `for..of` loops

Answer (score 1):

> Why for..in loop can not deal with the object but it comes Ok with Set()? Doesn't Set() return an Object?

I think you meant `for...of` loop (that's what your code uses), not `for...in`.

To use `for...of` on something, it has to be [*iterable*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#the_iterable_protocol) (it has to implement the standard way of getting an *iterator* from it). Objects are not iterable by default. `Array`, `Set`, `Map`, and `String` objects are iterable, and you can make your own iterable objects, but plain objects aren't iterable.

I assume you're using `Set` to remove duplicates (`"Burgers"` appears twice in `flatmenus`). You don't need that `forEach` call to put the values in the `Set`, you can pass `flatmenus` into `new Set` directly:

```
for (let dish of new Set(flatmenus)) {
    // ...
}
```

That works because the `Set` constructor accepts an iterable object and adds all of the values from its iterator to the `Set`. Arrays are iterable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
const menuSet=(menuArray)=> {
  let flatmenus = new Set(menuArray.flat());
  const menuCombined = document.querySelector('#combined-menu')
  flatmenus.forEach((dish)=>{
    let foodNode = document.createElement('li');
    foodNode.textContent = dish;
    menuCombined.appendChild(foodNode);
  });
}
menuSet([["Tacos", "Burgers"], ["Pizza"], ["Burgers", "Fries"]])
```

```html
<html><head><body><div id="combined-menu"></div></body></head></html>
```

Comment: Hello @mianbato, welcome to Stack Overflow. While the original poster (OP) could follow this approach to improve their code, I think your answer isn't answering the question that was originally asked: _"Why for..in loop can not deal with the object but it comes Ok with Set()? Doesn't Set() return an Object?"_, OP is mainly asking about why a Set can be iterated when a plain object cannot rather than looking for an alternative solution

Comment: Hi @NickParsons you'r right ,that's because the object needs to be iterable to use a for..in or for..of.